# I am looking to create a webpage similar to http://www.creativecrisp.com/

Tags: javascript, frameworks, html

I am looking to create a webpage similar to http://www.creativecrisp.com/
Any idea what framework was used to build this webpage? 
How it was done? 
Where should I start?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The chrome add-on [wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/) will show you what technologies each site you are on uses. Kind of fun and handy.

Answer (score 0):

The said website is build on *'Parallax Scrolling'* concept of website. You can find the additional information for the same on following links

[How to Create a Scrolling Parallax Website](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/create-scrolling-parallax-website/)

[How To Create A Parallax Scrolling Website](https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)

Answer (score 0):

It is a wordpress site. Using a newwave theme.

http://themeforest.net/item/newave-wordpress-responsive-one-page-parallax/6808797